# trying to trigger a tooltip when my checkbox is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

iI am using data attibutes to store the values of the checkboxes, its working fine but the tooltip is not triggering whenever the clss is updatated

here is my code for the tooltip

```
$(document).tooltip({
        classes: {
        "ui-tooltip": "uitooltip"
        },
        items: ".specialCheckbox2,.specialCheckbox3",
        content: function() {
            var el = $(this).find("input");
            if (el.is(":checked")) {
                return el.data("office");
            } else {
                return el.data("home");
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is how i am trying to update the data attribute on the onchange event and attributes do get updated but the mouseover showing tooltip does not hange

```
isNoApp can return true/false
if (isNoApp) {
            $('#w1_Day1').parent().addClass('specialCheckbox3').removeClass('specialCheckbox2');
            $('.specialCheckbox3 > input').attr('data-home','No Work allowed');
            $('.specialCheckbox3 > input').attr('data-office','No Work allowed');
        }else{
            $('#w1_Day1').parent().addClass('specialCheckbox2').removeClass('specialCheckbox3');
            $('.specialCheckbox2 > input').attr('data-home','Working');
            $('.specialCheckbox2 > input').attr('data-office','Working');
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Can you show your html?